# activemq dynamic discovery not working on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, activemq-classic

ActiveMQ dynamic discovery does not work in my prototype which has this objective: 
A JMS client app (message producer) which load balances request messages to multiple (2) JMS consumer 
apps.  There are 3 Amazon T2-micro EC2 instances running for this prototype  -
each instance runs activemq 5.14.4.  The load balancing is
achieved through a network of brokers which is created by static discovery 
network connectors configured on the activemq client instance activemq.xml file as:
               `<networkConnector
                  name="frontEnd->WMR1"
                  uri="static:(tcp://<publicip>:61616)"
                  duplex="true"
                  decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                  networkTTL="2"
                  dynamicOnly="true">
                  <excludedDestinations>
                      <topic physicalName="&gt;" />
                  </excludedDestinations>
               </networkConnector>
               <networkConnector
                  name="frontEnd->WMR2"
                  uri="static:(tcp://<publicip>:61616)"
                  duplex="true"
                  decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                  networkTTL="2"
                  dynamicOnly="true">
                  <excludedDestinations>
                     <topic physicalName="&gt;" />
                 </excludedDestinations>
               </networkConnector>`

The prototype with static discovery works perfectly and load balances any number of JMS-client messages 
to the 2 JMS-consumer applications.

However, I need to enhance the prototype to use dynamic (multicast) discovery to produce the network of brokers. So I tried:

```
    `<networkConnectors>
           <networkConnector uri="multicast://default"/>
    </networkConnectors>

    <transportConnectors>
         <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" discoveryUri="multicast://default"/>
    </transportConnectors>`
```

as directed in the documentation but the dynamic discovery does not work.  The transport and network connectors 
are created ok (I can see them on 
the activemq admin console) but they are empty  -  no message brokers were discovered via dynamic discovery.

I researched this problem exhaustively and at one point I found a post which suggested that 
the problem might be in the content of /etc/hosts  which is:

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

I need some help getting activemq dynamic discovery to work on EC2 Amazon T2-micro instances.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q. Does Amazon VPC support multicast or broadcast?**
>
> No.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/

The same is true for EC2 Classic.  The networks are not Ethernet, they're a software-defined emulation of Ethernet, allowing for far better scalability and security than would be practical with native Ethernet.

You can build an [overlay](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/6234671078671125) but there's little point in that for discovery purposes, since an overlay would require static configuration.